# I obtain a error syntax when I exceute one query

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I need to create table and I do this:

```
CREATE TABLE "home" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "address" varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

when I execute this query  I obtain this error:

```
Errore SQL [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"causali" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "address" va' at line 1
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"home" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "adddress" va' at line 1
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @Nick: the linked answer talks a lot about *backticks*, etc., but not at all about *double quoted* names (only jarlh's comment on the question mentions it)

Comment: @dnoeth the second answer on the linked question talks about double quotes.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, but who is going to read the 2nd answer when there's an accepted answer with such a high score :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not like double quotes on the table / column / alias names, until we enable [`ANSI_QUOTES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) mode.

> Treat " as an identifier quote character (like the ` quote character)
>   and not as a string quote character. You can still use backticks to quote
>   identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you
>   cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings because
>   they are interpreted as identifiers.

This mode is by default **Disabled**. Now, you can either use backticks around them, or use without double quotes (except when it is a [Reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), then you will have to use backticks around it).

```
CREATE TABLE home (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  address varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

Comment: Of course double quoted names are allowed, when you switch on ANSI_QUOTES (also part of ANSI sql mode)

Comment: These questions should be voted to close as duplicates, not answered.

Comment: @Nick I did not know if a dupe existed. If I know, I generally close vote specifying the dupe. Moreover, the accepted answer does not specify about ANSI_QUOTES mode.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya the second answer on the linked question talks about double quotes.

Comment: @Nick ok thanks. I did not go through all the answers. Will take note of this in particular question in future.